# R 4.2.2 on Ubuntu Server 22.10

Tags: r, ubuntu

I try to install R 4.2.2 but it is able to install only 4.2.1.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  r-base-core :
> Depends: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable
> Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
> packages.

I have

> libicu-dev is already the newest version (71.1-3ubuntu1).

Could be that is not yet supported for 22.10? or is there any turnaround to install it?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you run to install it?

Comment: Generally one is suppose to update ones Linux installation before installing new packages.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the status of 22.10, though. https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ only lists up to 22.04. Maybe 22.10/Kinetic Kudu is included in the repo but the web page hasn't been updated ... ??

Comment: FWIW, Conda Forge distributes R 4.2.2. Works perfectly fine on an `ubuntu:22.10` Docker container, installed via Micromamba. Similar to `c2d4u`, all Conda Forge R package builds are precompiled (fast installs) and pull in their non-R dependencies.

Comment: @IRTFM --- it is a fresh OS installation and all updates/upgrades were done before start installing any extra tool/packages, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893876/how-to-install-libicu-dev-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am running ubuntu 22.10 and had the same problem. I have solved it via:

```
wget http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb
```

then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with this lib to install php8.2-intl and your answer did the trick!