# installation impossible R on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-23.10

I'm encountering difficulties while trying to install R on my Ubuntu system using the `sudo apt install r-base` command.

The installation process is interrupted with the following error message:

> The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies:
> r-base-core : Dependency: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable
> Depends on: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but cannot be installed
> Recommended: r-base-dev but will not be installed
> E: Unable to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.

I've attempted to install R using the standard package manager, but it seems to be halted due to unresolved dependencies. I'm not sure how to address the issues mentioned in the error message, and I'm seeking guidance on resolving these dependencies and successfully installing R on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261666/r-4-2-2-on-ubuntu-server-22-10

Comment: @BenBolker no : The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies:
 r-base-core: Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
               Recommended: r-recommended but will not be installed
               Recommended: r-base-dev but will not be installed
               Recommended: r-doc-html but will not be installed
E: Unable to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.

Comment: See my longer answer below but I think I also have done at time what Ben suggests here and 'one by one' plucked the missing libraries in.  I am suggested an alternative below.

Comment: @Stefan_aus_hannover  The key issue is using a 22.04 build on a 23.10 system. Some of the 'assumed on 22.04' library version are at a higher major number in 23.10.  Cheers, Dirk_aus_braunschweig

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover The difference is that Ubuntu releases every six months as you can ascertain from looking at [packages.ubuntu.com and searching libicu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=icu&searchon=sourcenames&suite=all&section=all) that different releases can end up with different version.  Which is what happens here, and which is why I rebuilt on 23.04 (which I ran at the time) to have it built against the version in use.  This is how it is supposed to work.  And yes, I have been a Debian maintainer since 1995.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover That is *absolutely false*. I have been running Ubuntu since about 2007 or 2008, updated every six month, and kept R packages in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-packages/` without a need for reinstall (unless R forced it for packages in 3.5, 3.6, 4.0, ...).  And with [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) you now get 22,500 CRAN + BioC packages with *full* apt integration and no missing libraries.  So let's just stop here.  If you want to discuss this further, the [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/) list is a better place.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover Dude there are _different modalities_ and you are of course free to compile whatever you want whenever you want.  I do / have done the same with daily build (from source, Linux) off CRAN for decades on either Debian and/or Ubuntu.  Yet what you stated about Ubuntu was **demonstrably false** and, frankly, misleading FUD.  But you seem incorrectible which makes this my last message too you.  Life too short and all that.